# What is the direction of gravitational constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, gravity, newtonian-gravity

Our book says:

$$\vec F=\dfrac{GMm}{r^2}$$

If  Force is a vector quantity, $G$ must also be vector quantity so what is the direction of $G$.

***I am a school kid please explain simply and kindly***

Comment: Why do you think that $G$ should be a vector? You could have easily said that for $m$ instead?

Comment: m is  scalar I know

Comment: Then G is also a number only. Read Steeven's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$G$ is not a vector quantity, but just a number - a so-called *scalar* quantity - just like mass $m$. True, force *is* a vector quantity, but the formula you show here is **a formula for the "size" of the force** only!

The "size" or "strength" of a vector is called the *magnitude*. Some formulas give magnitudes only, other formulas give directions and yet other formulas give the full vector quantity including both its magnitude and direction. The formula you showed here does not give the direction, but only the magnitude of the force.

Compare these two formulas:

$$F=G\frac{Mm}{d^2}\qquad,\qquad \vec F=G\frac{Mm}{d^2}\hat r$$

The first formula gives the force magnitude $F$. That is the one you showed. The second gives the full force vector $\vec F$. In the second one, there is included a **unit direction vector** that points in the direction of the force, which I here call $\hat r$. (A unit vector is a vector with a magnitude of 1.) Without this, the direction is not involved at all because - as you rightfully question - none of the other parameters are vectors.

<sub>*(You might here and there see other versions of this formula depending on how $\hat r$ is defined. For instance, on this [Wikipedia page](http://Hi%20@TechDroid,%20thank%20you%20for%20your%20feedback.%20I%20have%20updated%20the%20answer%20slightly%20to%20make%20it%20a%20bit%20more%20layman-friendly.%20I%20hope%20this%20makes%20things%20clearer.%20Regarding%20your%20question:) as well as in an answer below they have flipped $\hat r$ to mean the opposite of how I have used it, and then they add a minus sign so the formula still fits. And in another answer below, a different symbol $\mathbf e$ is used, which isn't a unit vector, so it must be divided by its length $d$ so it still fits (so that $\hat r=\frac{\mathbf e}d$). It is thus important that it is clear each time what such parameters exactly mean.)*</sub>

Comment: He requested simple steeven, he/she is most likely not there yet. And do you tend to say acceleration is a scalar? I'm also learning alright.

Comment: Are you sure about the sign in that vector equation? ;-)

Comment: You should explain what the direction of $\hat{r}$ is just in case, although it might be obvious it is the main question of the thread

Comment: Hi @TechDroid, thank you for your feedback. I have updated the answer slightly to make it a bit more layman-friendly. I hope this makes things clearer. Regarding your question, I do not understand why you would ask about acceleration here? Acceleration is a vector quantity with a magnitude and a direction as well - but that is for another answer.

Comment: @mmeent and TheAverageHijano. Thank you for your feedback. I have added the description of the direction of $\hat r$ and given a note regarding the sign convention (I will avoid using negative signs here as that is not the point).

Comment: @ Steeven. My bad, I was off thinking $G$ is gravitational acceleration constant.

Answer (score 2):

You are right in that the force is a vector quantity, but the standard formula you give only describes its magnitude, how big it is. Hence none of the values in it ($G,m,M,d$) is a vector.

To get a vector one needs to multiply the magnitude with a (unit) direction. For a central force this will point from the mass under consideration towards the other one. If they are in locations $\mathbf{x_m}$ and $\mathbf{x_M}$ you get the distance $d=||\mathbf{x_M}-\mathbf{x_m}||$ and a unit vector pointing in the right direction $\mathbf{e}=\frac{\mathbf{x_M}-\mathbf{x_m}}{||\mathbf{x_M}-\mathbf{x_m}||}$. The full formula would hence be $$\mathbf{F}=\frac{GMm}{d^2}\frac{\mathbf{e}}{d}.$$

The last factor is often left out in texts and calculations since it is assumed that we know where gravity is pointed or calculations anyway only deal with the magnitude of the force, not its direction. But when simulating gravity between point masses the full formula is needed.

Comment: The force expression has the wrong units. In particular, $\boldsymbol{\mathrm e} / d$ should just be $\boldsymbol{\mathrm e}$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are worried that the equation in the book relates a vector quantity $\vec F$ to a scalar quantity $\dfrac{GMm}{r^2}$ which is not allowed and to are looking for a vector on the right hand side of your equation?

There is a convention which is used when the force $\vec F$ is quantified.

Suppose that there are two bodies of mass $m_1$ and mass $m_2$ separated by a distance $r$.

The magnitude of the gravitation force of attraction between the two bodies is $\dfrac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$.

One now needs to assign a direction to the two forces - $\vec F_{\text {1 due to 2}}$, force on mass $1$ due to attraction of mass $2$ and $\vec F_{\text {2 due to 1}}$ force on mass $2$ due to attraction of mass $1$ with $\vec F_{\text {2 due to 1}} = - \vec F_{\text {1 due to 2}}$ which is Newton's third law.

To proceed further a direction is needed and this is often done by choosing a unit vector $\hat r$ (a vector which has a magnitude of 1) which is parallel to the line joining the two masses.
This is equivalent to deciding which direction is positive).

Now one need to decide as to the actual direction of the unit vector (positive direction).
Is it from mass $1$ pointing towards mass $2$ or the other way round?

Suppose the unit vector $\hat r$ points from mass $1$ towards mass $2$ then

$$\vec F_{\text {2 due to 1}}= \, \dfrac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}\,(-\hat r)= - \, \dfrac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}\,\hat r$$

Note the minus sign which means that the force on mass $2$ due to mass $1$ is towards mass $1$ ie in the opposite direction to the direction of the unit vector ie negative direction.

This is a convention which is used to show a difference between an attractive force (negative) and a repulsive force (positive) which you will probably meet when studying electrostatics.

Often $M$ is used for the mass of an object (eg Earth) with has a mass much greater than the other object (eg satellite) of mass $m$ and the unit vector / positive direction is from the Earth to the satellite.

$$\vec F_{\text {satellite due to Earth}}= -\dfrac{GMm}{r^2}\,\hat r$$

Answer (score 0):

Sources of gravity always try to pull masses towards them so the direction of the force gravity of every planet and star in the universe is towards the mass center of the planet/star.